# Installed Python2.7 on centos 6 and now pip points to Python2.7 instead of Python version

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos

I have installed Python 2.7 in my centos 6 linux box and when I install any packages using easy_install and pip install its installing in Python2.7...I need to install few packages in my default Python2.6 and how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can check your pip version and which python it is pointed to

```
pip --version
```

That should give you some information about what to expect when calling pip. If you have pip 0.8 or better you can try `pip-{version}`.

```
pip-2.6 install some-package-you-want-in-2.6
pip-2.7 install some-package-you-want-in-2.7
```

If you are still having problems you are calling the correct version of python. Check that your $PYTHON_PATH env var points to Python 2.6.

```
echo $PYTHON_PATH
```

Will tell you where it is pointed at now. The value is likely set in your ~/.bashrc file. If that comes back blank you should [set the PYTHON_PATH variable](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4) so you can easily configure what Python you are calling from the shell. Without the variable you shell will call the python linked in /usr/bin, changing the symlinking in /usr/bin which might give you headaches down the road because you'll be altering global behavior in your system.

Comment: Good. If you need to change default python interpreter you can use a symlink "ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/local/bin/python".

Comment: echo $PYTHON_PATH prints blank

Comment: If Python_path is not set, which python_path will my PATH look for

Comment: did that fix your prob?

Comment: Still same problem after setting the $PYTHON_PATH, echo $PYTHON_PATH = usr/bin/python....echo $PATH = /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/root/bin

Comment: usr/bin/python you putting the symlink to 2.7 on your path

Comment: Is it because my LOCAL is pointed first in the PATH library and then the usr/bin/

Comment: Your system creates it. `ls -l /usr/bin | grep python` will list all of the pyhton links you have there

Comment: when I do python..it takes my python2.6 console correctly and when I do python2.7 ..it takes to python2.7 console correctly..which means its not symlink

Comment: [root@linuxhost bin]# which python
/usr/bin/python
[root@linuxhost bin]# which python2.7
/usr/local/bin/python2.7

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48082/discussion-between-user1050619-and-jeremyjjbrown)